# Convert Map<String, String> to Custom Class having instance variables and Map<String, String> as one of instance variable

Tags: java, java-8

I have `Map<String, String>`, where key is mapped to `Class` fields. I need to convert this map to create `Test object` with the Map key/value

Ex. `Map<"type", "type1">`

```
class Test {
    private String type;
}
```

Is there any utility that does this in java or any custom code refernce that can help me achieve this

Comment: Just googling your title found the answer, please for the future, do some research before posting a question on Stackoverflow

Comment: I need to make some customization as I will have private Map<String, String> coordinates instance variable in my pojo class. I need something that I can override

Comment: we found your question to be a duplicate. Please, follow the pinned link and you will probably find the answer